# Unity Rigidbody2D center of mass with polygon collider calculation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

If I use a polygon collider, the center of mass of a rigidbody2d is no longer the center of the object.

Thus, if I make calls to rigidbody2d.applyForceAtPosition, I cannot move an object forward with the parameters `(position.x,position.y+1)` `(position.x,position.y-1)` without also creating torque.

Is there any call so I can do
`(centerofmass.x, centeroffmass.y+1)`?

Since Unity has a rigidbody2d.addtorque call that applies torque at the center of mass, there must be a way of determining center of mass?

According to http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/210977-Rigidbody2D-Center-of-Mass-Sprites-rotating-irregularly it's not in Unity 4.3 but is there any way to obtain it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that [rigidbody2D.AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) adds the force to the center of mass, just the same way AddTorgue applies it to the center of mass.

Comment: addForce does apply to CoM but there's no way to effectively use applyForceAtPosition without knowledge of CoM position.